# Reading file from txt file but is not inside the Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift2

Need help regarding getting the txt file which is not located in the xcode project. Is there any way to retrieve the txt file without having the txt file inside the xcode project?

```
var  data:[[String:String]] = []
var  columnTitles:[String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func reportData(_ sender: Any) {
      printData()
}

@IBAction func resetData(_ sender: Any) {
     textView.text = "Nope, no Pizza here"
}


@IBAction func readData(_ sender: Any) {
      textView.text = readDataFromFile(file: "/Users/mpsip/Desktop/TextFileCSVDemo/data")
}


@IBAction func writeData(_ sender: Any) {
    if writeDataToFile(file: "data") {
        print("data written")
    } else {
        print("data not written")
    }
}


func cleanRows(file:String)->String{
    //use a uniform \n for end of lines.
    var cleanFile = file
    cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")
    cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")

    return cleanFile
}

func getStringFieldsForRow(row:String, delimiter:String)-> [String]{

    return row.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
}

func convertCSV(file:String){

    let rows = cleanRows(file: file).components(separatedBy: "\n")
    if rows.count > 0 {
        data = []
        columnTitles = getStringFieldsForRow(row: rows.first!,delimiter:",")
        for row in rows{
            let fields = getStringFieldsForRow(row: row,delimiter: ",")
            if fields.count != columnTitles.count {continue}
            var dataRow = [String:String]()
            for (index,field) in fields.enumerated(){
                dataRow[columnTitles[index]] = field
            }
            data += [dataRow]
        }
    } else {
        print("No data in file")
    }
}

func printData(){
    convertCSV(file: textView.text)
    var tableString = ""
    var rowString = ""
    print("data: \(data)")
    for row in data{
        rowString = ""
        for fieldName in columnTitles{
            guard let field = row[fieldName] else{
                print("field not found: \(fieldName)")
                continue
            }
            rowString += field + "\t"
        }
        tableString += rowString + "\n"
    }
    textView.text = tableString
}

//MARK: Data reading and writing functions
func writeDataToFile(file:String)-> Bool{
    // check our data exists
    guard let data = textView.text else {return false}
    print(data)
    //get the file path for the file in the bundle
    // if it doesnt exist, make it in the bundle
    var fileName = file + ".txt"
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "txt"){
        fileName = filePath
    } else {
        fileName = Bundle.main.bundlePath + fileName
    }

    //write the file, return true if it works, false otherwise.
    do{
        try data.write(toFile: fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8 )
        return true
    } catch{
        return false
    }
}

func readDataFromFile(file:String)-> String!{
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "txt")
        else {
            return nil
    }
    do {

       // let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, usedEncoding: String.Encoding.)


        let contents = try String (contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return contents
    } catch {
        print ("File Read Error")
        return nil
    }
}
```

For this line
textView.text = readDataFromFile(file: "/Users/mpsip/Desktop/TextFileCSVDemo/data")
how do I know what is the correct file path from my application or iPad?

Comment: Apps are sandboxed. And your apps is on your iPad, while you are giving it a path of your Mac ? Make no sense at all.

Comment: Then do you have any idea regarding the file path for the gallery? And apps that are sandboxed what is their file path or it doesn't allow users to know the file path? I just giving an example regarding the path of my Mac as I had no idea what to insert yet so i randomly just entered my Mac path instead.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone and iPad applications run in their own sandbox. Applications do not have an access to resources outside the application sandbox. So basically whether the file is their in your Xcode project or not is not important (whether the file is part of the main bundle or not is not important as you can download file and write it as well), what is important though is whether the file is in your app's sandbox or not.

If the file is present in app's document/temp directory, you can read it. You can download the file dynamically on app launch from hosted servers and write it to the app's document/temp directory and read it whenever you want it, or else ,add the file to the application bundle (add the file to the Xcode project) and ship it.